# sort a list based on the datetime portion of records where datetime position in record may vary

Tags: awk, sed, sort

I want to sort a list on the datetime portion of its name.

Is this possible using sort? I cannot specify the sort column as the column may vary as shown in sample input below.

```
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172654_20425.log
package_user_20171227172949_5627.log
swid_state_definition_user_20171227162839_6515.log
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172732_23839.log
swid_appsrv_stop_user_20171227172258_27116.log
package_user_20171227172610_16198.log
swid_state_definition_user_20171227172344_322.log
package_user_20171227233634_23845.log
package_user_20171227162858_7082.log
```

I can reverse the order of fields through e.g.

```
awk -F_ '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i"_"};printf "\n"}'
```

then sort with -d_  -k2,2 then reverse order of fields back to retain the original file name - purging residual delimiters with e.g. sed - but this gets awkward.

```
awk -F_ '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i"_"};printf "\n"}' | sort -t'_' -k2,2 \
| awk -F_ '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i"_"};printf "\n"}' | sed 's/^_//' \ 
| sed 's/_$//'
```

How would you approach this?

I was thinking along the lines of using sed to break out the datetime portion via regex and pipe that into sort and then use some built-in to recover the full filename and not only the matched regex, when printing the output.

Hoping I didn't produce another duplicate, I cannot really summarise the problem statement

Comment: oops, i think this might be a duplicate after all:-) looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680561/bash-sort-by-regexp

Comment: it's a good case to delete your question

Comment: Well, we can't close as a duplicate if the dup doesn't exist on the same site, so I would assume it's fine.

Comment: too late for delete as other already responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1), $0}' | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

This uses `awk` with `_` as the field separator to copy the second-last field (**datetime**) to the beginning of the line, then uses `sort` to sort the input numerically on that field only, followed by `cut` to remove the extra field.

Example output with your sample input saved to a file called `file`:

```
$ awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1), $0}' file  | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
swid_state_definition_user_20171227162839_6515.log
package_user_20171227162858_7082.log
swid_appsrv_stop_user_20171227172258_27116.log
swid_state_definition_user_20171227172344_322.log
package_user_20171227172610_16198.log
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172654_20425.log
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172732_23839.log
package_user_20171227172949_5627.log
package_user_20171227233634_23845.log
```

This assumes that the datetime is always going to be in the second-last field.  If that is **not** the case, then if you are using GNU awk you could capture the pattern which *looks* like a datetime, and prepend that to the beginning of the line:

```
$ awk -F_ '{match($0,"_(20[0-9]{12})_",dt); print dt[1], $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1 -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

but I'd be inclined to use `perl` in this case.

GNU awk's `match()` function takes an optional third arrgument, the name of an array variable to store any captured matches in.  In this case, there's only going to be one capture, so that'll be stored in the first element of the array, e.g. `dt[1]`.   IIRC, POSIX awk still doesn't have any way to capture regex matches.

BTW, the assumption now is that the year is >= 2000.  Adjust the regex to suit if that isn't always going to be true for your input data.

Comment: Fantastic. thanks for your help. the response is clear, it explains all the steps, it assumes nothing but works for more general cases. thumbs up cas

Comment: heh. i just noticed that if you google for "sort by second-last" or "sort by last" column, answers almost identical to this have been posted here and to other SE sites and elsewhere, so it is a dupe after all.  It's a variation of common technique known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) or, more generally, as **decorate-sort-undecorate**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zsh` globs here like:

```
printf '%s\n' *_user_*.log(oe:'REPLY=${REPLY##*user_}':)
```

where `oe:...:` defines a sorting order based on the given expression. Here where we select the part of the file name to the right of "user_".

To sort on the last 2 `_*`:

```
printf '%s\n' *_*_*.log(oe:'REPLY=${(M)REPLY%_*_*}':)
```

Comment: yes, that works but only in case the datetime portion is preceded by user_ , sorry, i didn't specify that

Comment: @HenrikJson see edit for the last two `_*`.

Comment: ok, got it, nice

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work:

```
$ perl -e 'sub key($) { $_[0] =~ /(\d+)_\d+\.log$/; return $1; }; 
     @lines = <>; print sort {key($a) cmp key($b)}  @lines;'  < files
swid_state_definition_user_20171227162839_6515.log
package_user_20171227162858_7082.log
swid_appsrv_stop_user_20171227172258_27116.log
swid_state_definition_user_20171227172344_322.log
package_user_20171227172610_16198.log
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172654_20425.log
swid_ds_install_user_20171227172732_23839.log
package_user_20171227172949_5627.log
package_user_20171227233634_23845.log
```

The subroutine `key` picks the string of digits based on the fact that the datetime appears to always be the second-to-last part of the filename, before the `.log` and the other number field. Then we read the input lines in, and print them sorted using the output of `key()` as the sort key.

Perl's `sort` can take an inline code block that gets the values to be compared as `$a` and `$b`, and `cmp` returns less-then, equal, or greater-than (comparing as strings).

If the location of the timestamp could actually vary more, we could change the sub to pick a string of 14 digits anywhere in the string, e.g. separated by underscores here:

```
sub key($) { $_[0] =~ /_(\d{14})_/; return $1; }
```